# Linux OS Execution Command in Lua to Shutdown OS - Help a Newbie to Understand

Tags: linux, lua

I'm using the following command string in Lua to shutdown my Linux system if the user fails to access the system properly:

```
os.execute 'sleep 5 && echo password | sudo -S poweroff'
```

I know the following:

**os.execute** = simple Lua command to execute an OS command.
**sleep 5** = pause "X" amount of time prior to doing next command.
**&&** = AND (simple enough and has numerous meanings but this instance, do both sides of &&).
**echo** = Linux's version of "print" in Lua.

But please help me understand the rest.  I know what sudo means, but why is the root password ***before*** "sudo"?  Why the pipe deliminator?  Why use "-S" with sudo which means Stdin in Linux?

Is there another way to have a script in Lua to shutdown/reboot an OS?

Comment: [a better place to ask](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You could configure `sudo` thru `/etc/sudoers` to avoid typing the password (of course, this has some negative security implications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this in pieces:

1. `sleep 5` : Block for 5 seconds
2. `&&` : And only if this succeeds (it will!) - yet another meaning of
   "and"
3. `echo password` : Write password
4. `|` : Whatever is output from the command before (in this case the
   password), do not write it out, but use it as input for
   the next command ... a pipe is, when what comes out of one thing is
   directed into the next thing ;-)
5. `sudo -S` : act as the system administrator, but don't ask for the
   password (there is nobody there), instead use whatever comes from the
   standard input as the password
6. `poweroff` : This is the command to run as system administrator

Summed up: After waiting 5 seconds, give the password to sudo, which executes poweroff

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!!  I knew what some of it meant but couldn't piece it all together.  I need to do something to understand all of this better!!!

Answer (score 1):

The pipe redirects the standard output of the command before `|` to the standard input of the command after `|`.

So, `echo password` outputs `password`, which is used as the standard input for `sudo -S poweroff`. And from the manual of [`sudo`](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudo.man.html):

> The `‑S` (stdin) option causes `sudo` to read the password from the standard input instead of the terminal device. The password must be followed by a newline character.

It makes `sudo` to read password from `stdin`, in this case, is exactly the output of `echo password`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  Unfortunately I can only give the answer to one person or you both would get it!  Thank you!